# Set decimals for QJsonValue

Tags: c++, qt

If I do:

```
  auto jsonValue = QJsonValue(0.1);
  auto jsonObj = QJsonObject();
  jsonObj.insert("Key", jsonValue);
  QJsonDocument jsonDoc(jsonObj);    
  auto json = jsonDoc.toJson();    
  std::cout << json.toStdString() << std::endl;
```

I get:

```
{
    "Key": 0.10000000000000001
}
```

But I would like:

```
{
    "Key": 0.1
}
```

Is this at least possible with Qt?

I use Qt 5.6.

I works fine for Qt 5.9 and Qt 5.11. Not tested with 5.10 but it should also work hopefully.

PS: I know why 0.1 becomes 0.10000000000000001

Comment: What if you use string values instead? I.e. `auto jsonValue = QJsonValue("0.1");`

Comment: @vahancho I think the output will be `"Key": "0.1"` instead of `"Key": 0.1`

Comment: @eyllanesc, right. That's what I meant. When read this value, it can be converted to double. But I don't know whether OP is bound to particular JSON scheme.

Comment: What is your Qt version? I am using Qt5.11.2 msvc x64, and I get 0.1 in debug and release.

Comment: @eyllanesc std::cout

Comment: If you already know why 0.1 becomes 0.10000000000000001 (i.e., the fraction 1/10 is impossible to represent in binary floating point), then surely you're already aware that any decimal stringification will necessarily be an approximation. @vahancho has the right idea: serialize your numbers as strings!

Comment: I just tested and as noted @张铁男 I get 0.1 :-)

Comment: IMO this is bug in Qt (it tries to print value beyond `double` precision), check if it is not already reported.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist this is not a duplicate since it is different library. Here you have Qt, and the other is Jsoncpp.

Comment: @MarekR This is a json issue, not a library issue. I asked about the exact same problem.

Comment: @vahancho: yes, I need to send a double value, not a string.

Comment: Qt version is 5.6.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist can you explain why this is JSon issue and not library implementation issue? Note that Qt tries print value beyond precision of `double` type (it tires to print 17 significant digits), so it is clearly library bug.

Comment: @PedroLM: it may be possible in Qt to use something like QByteArray::number(0.1, 'f', 4) and inject it in my QJsonObject. But I didn't find the solution yet.

Comment: @MarekR Because according to the json standard, doubles are doubles and can't be interpreted otherwise. So there's no way around it. You may be lucky to find an implementation that deviates from there, but then that's not standard json.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: I really do not care about the standard actually. I just want my 0.1 to be serialized as 0.1. It seems actually that Qt 5.11 may take this into account though. Only problem is: I need to stick with 5.6.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist I don't get it `0.1` is a `double` too which will properly represent this value. It should not be represented as `0.10000000000000001` since it doesn't provide any extra information.

Comment: @Korchkidu Qt uses the standard for it returns the decimals, in the standard does not indicate the decimals of precision so a possible solution is to parse the QString that returns toJson () and eliminate those decimals.

Comment: @MarekR: 0.1 cannot be represented using floating-point representation.

Comment: @eyllanesc: yes, that may be a good solution.

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist: this is not a duplicate as it is specific to Qt. I want to find a solution to "inject" 0.1 in the final QJsonDocument.

Comment: @Korchkidu I know that OP knows that. My point is that parsing `0.1` and `0.10000000000000001` to `double` leads to exactly same representation. There is no point to print this value with such precision since it doesn't cray any extra information! That is why I'm claiming it is Qt bug. When value is printed the outcome should be limited to something whne parsed will restore original `double` value. `0.1` is fulfilling this requirement.

Comment: @MarekR: you are actually right. It is a Qt bug. It has been fixed from (at least) Qt 5.9.